# get datetime difference as 1day, 2hours, 30mins

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want the difference of two `datetime` columns like `1day , 2hours, 3min.`

I have tried with this,

```
DECLARE @end datetime2 = '2013-11-13 09:35:49.007'
DECLARE @start datetime2 =  '2013-11-12 17:34:11.533'

select datediff(day, @start, @end) days,
datediff(HOUR, @start, @end) Hours,
datediff(MINUTE, @start, @end) Minutes
```

the output is

```
1day    16hours 961minutes.
```

but i want output like  `1day 4hours 30min.`

need some help to solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in your sample is 16 hours, 1 minute and 38 seconds. Where did you come up with 1 day, 4 hours and 30 minutes? 17:34 is 5:34 PM, not 5:34 AM.

Here's code that will do the descriptive text from the date difference. Note: To address edge case of 0 weeks, days, hours etc, you'll have to check before doing the cast.

```
DECLARE @end datetime2 = '2013-11-13 09:35:49.007'
DECLARE @start datetime2 =  '2013-11-12 17:34:11.533'

SELECT ''
    +  CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @start, @end) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' weeks, '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @start, @end) / 60 / 60 / 24 % 7 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' days, '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @start, @end) / 60 / 60 % 24  AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' hours, '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @start, @end) / 60 % 60 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' minutes and '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @start, @end) % 60 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' seconds.';
```

**Output:**

```
0 weeks, 0 days, 16 hours, 1 minutes and 38 seconds.
```